# Group by with count along with total count in all the rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am performing group by to get the count of every individual value along with the total count.

Data,

[image]

It is very easy to get the count of individual columns using below queries,

```
select name, colour, count(1) from table group by name, colour;
select colour, count(1) from table group by colour;
```

I need both the results in a single query. Expected result is,

[image]

I need total count of Name in every row with respect to Colour.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Missed to specify group by clause. Thanks @jarlh

Comment: Why do you write `COUNT(1)` and not `COUNT(name)`? This might be valid syntax and my opinion might be wrong. But I think this is bad style and just kind of laziness to do not write the column name.

Comment: @JonasMetzler they do different things don't they? I use `1` when I want a count of rows rather than non-null values/expressions.  Interesting to see other view points!

Comment: Ah ok, you use it instead of `COUNT(*)`? I think this is misleading, but should work anyway.

Comment: @JonasMetzler yup, has the same semantics and all optimisers should treat it as such.  Don't think I'd actually use it bare, but have it in a `case` expression to aggregate over the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `count()` :

```
select distinct name, colour, 
       count(1) over (partition by Name, colour) as count_by_name_colour, 
       count(1) over (partition by name) as count_by_name
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1NMGL9mT)

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Create the table
DROP TABLE if exists your_table;
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    colour VARCHAR(255)
);

-- Insert sample data
INSERT INTO your_table (name, colour)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Red'),
    ('Sara', 'Blue'),
    ('John', 'Red'),
    ('Mike', 'Green'),
    ('Sara', 'Blue'),
    ('John', 'Green');

-- Query 1: Calculate counts using window functions
SELECT DISTINCT
    name,
    colour,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY name, colour) AS count_by_name_colour,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS count_by_name
FROM mytable;

-- Query2 to get individual and total counts
WITH IndividualCounts AS (
  SELECT name, colour, COUNT(*) AS individual_count
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY name, colour
),
TotalCounts AS (
  SELECT colour, COUNT(*) AS total_count
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY colour
)
SELECT
  ic.name,
  ic.colour,
  ic.individual_count,
  tc.total_count
FROM
  IndividualCounts ic
JOIN
  TotalCounts tc
ON
  ic.colour = tc.colour;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with name_colour as (
    select 
        name, colour, count(1) as count_by_name_colour,
    from mytable
        -- add where clause if needed 
        group by name, colour
), nme as (
    select 
        name, count(1) as count_by_name
    from mytable
    -- add where clause if needed 
        group by name
)
select 
    nc.name,
    nc.colour,
    nc.count_by_name_colour,
    n.count_by_name
from name_colour nc left join nme n on nc.name = n.name
```

Comment: Why query the table multiple times (this will likely be much slower) and not use a window function? They were introduced for exactly such use cases.

Comment: Completely agree on that